# ag-grid angular 2 dynamic cell HTML

Tags: angular, ag-grid

trying to get bindings to work in a cell template.

ideally something like this:

```
this.columnDefs = [
        { headerName: "ID", field: "ID", hide: true },
        { headerName: "Name", field: "NAME", width: 400, template: '<a [href]="productUrl">{{data.NAME}}</a>',
```

**update**

just noticed this in the documentation :/

> Angular Compiling is NOT supported inside ag-Grid for Angular 2.

**possible solution 1**

as a workaround I am adding a column with pre-constructed html:

```
this.Products.forEach((p:any) => p['url'] = '<a href="http://blah/'+ p.ID +'">' + p.NAME + '</a>')
```

however this renders as escaped html. if I need to use a template I believe I am back to square one

**workaround 2**

(cellClicked)="cellClicked($event)"

```
cellClicked($event){
    var p = $event.node.data; // product object
    window.location.href = this.productUrl + p.ID;
}
...
{ headerName: "Name", field: "NAME", width: 400, cellClass: 'btn btn-link' },
```

this could work for a link column, but not being able to add any dynamic HTML is kind of a non starter..

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it for performance, but cellRenderer can be used in this scenario. (performance is a concern since each cell will trigger this function)

```
{ headerName: "Name", field: "NAME", width: 400, cellRenderer: function(pars){
      return pars.node.data.linkHtml;
} }
```

***pars.node.data*** is the underlying object behind the row. linkHtml is appended to the object like this (this logic could also be done in renderer):

```
this.Products.forEach(
    (p:any) => p['url'] = '<a href="'+ this.productUrl + p.ID +'">' + p.NAME + '</a>'
```

I will report back with performance implication once this is tested more